# Task scheduler wrapper throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, scheduling

I am using Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper(http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/). I've created a code which works perfectly at Windows 7. But when I am trying to run it against windows xp, I am getting an exception: "Task.get_Xml is not supported on Task Scheduler 1.0".

Does anyone meet with the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using IRegisteredTask.  The docs are quite clear, Vista required.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you  are going to have work around this issue manually. Not all methods are available for Task Scheduler 1.0 which is available for Windows XP.

- [Task Scheduler 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756979.aspx)

The redesigned Task Scheduler 2.0 is installed with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. Task Scheduler 1.0 is installed with the Windows Server 2003 family, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 operating systems.